# Flink 1.5 on yarn, how to disable dynamic resource allocate?

Tags: flink-streaming

https://flink.apache.org/news/2017/11/22/release-1.4-and-1.5-timeline.html.
FLIP-6:"Containers are requested as needed and will be released when not used any more".

It will take all resource from yarn. So, how to disable dynamic allocate of containers or set a max value to flink ResourceManager.

Comment: use flink-1.5.0-rc from https://github.com/apache/flink/releases/tag/release-1.5.0-rc1

Answer (score 0):

set configuration mode to legacy to disable dynamic resource allocation. ref: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/config.html#legacy